# How to download Excel file by Ajax in Laravel?

Tags: angular, laravel, laravel-5, maatwebsite-excel

I use this [library](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel) to export Excel

I send POST request to endpoint, where method retrieves data and creates file:

```
return Excel::download(new EventsExport($request), $filename);
```

Problem is that I get this file as binary in response, and browser does not start download it.

How to fix it?

Comment: Are you setting your headers to utilize the proper CSV headers?

Comment: Sure, I think problem in client side, how to download file using Angular

Comment: If you're using Angular, you should add that as a tag, and include the Angular related code. You've only posted about the Laravel aspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about angular, but if you are in laravel you can,

call a ajax request to your controller

then create a temporary excel file with your data.

then simply download it via this header.

`header('Content-Type: text/csv');
echo file_get_contents('your_file_location_url');`

then unlink your temp file if you want to

Answer (score 1):

If you are making the request as an AJAX request from your SPA the download won't start. You need to either make the endpoint accept GET-requests and link the user to that URL or embed a form to you SPA app that will do a normal POST to the endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

after some struggling, here the simplest solution i found

**Your controller**

```
return Excel::download(new EventsExport($request), $filename, null, [\Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::XLS] );
```

**Your frontend**

```
 var data = match=3&win=false; //example
 var url = "{{route($routeForYourExcel)}}?" + data;
 window.open(url, '_blank');
```

Hope it help

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
     type : 'GET',
     url : '/download-excel',
     success:function(){
         window.location.href = '/download-excel';
     }
});
```

Comment: Please include an explanation of the code in your answer.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

I think proper way is to store it on your server and send link to your ajax request:

```
return response()->json([
    'url' => 'url-to-stored-file'
]);
```

And in AJAX response you can do:

```
function(data) {
    window.location.href = data.url;
}
```

I know this is not preferable way to do it but it works

Comment: I don't think this answers the OP's question. They're wanting to download an Excel file, not send JSON in the response.

Comment: Yes, what headers send from client?

Comment: I think you don't need any aditional headers. For this you just need to get a json response and navigate your window url to it

Comment: I get file path like: `C:\Projects\events\Backend\storage\app/events/1.xls`

Comment: If pass this to browser url it starts download. but it does not work in code

Comment: Oh, you're working on local environment. perheps you don't have file permission or you need navigate browser to: `file://C:\Projects\events\Backend\storage\app/events/1.xls` I don't know windows well